# Languages that support boolean syntactic sugar

Tags: language-features, boolean-logic, syntactic-sugar

There's a certain over-verbosity that I have to engage in when writing certain Boolean expressions, at least with all the languages I've used, and I was wondering if there were any languages that let you write more concisely?

The way it goes is like this:

I want to find out if I have a `Thing` that can be either `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D`.

And I'd like to see if `Thing` is an `A` or a `B`.

The logical way for me to express this is

```
//1:  true if Thing is an A or a B
Thing == (A || B)
```

Yet all the languages I know expect it to be written as

```
//2:  true if Thing is an A or a B
Thing == A || Thing == B
```

Are there any languages that support 1?  It doesn't seem problematic to me, unless `Thing` is a Boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Icon does.

As a simple example, here is how to get the sum of all numbers less than 1000 that are divisble by three or five (the first problem of Project Euler).

```
procedure main ()
    local result
    local n
    result := 0
    every n := 1 to 999 do
        if n % (3 | 5) == 0 then
            result +:= n
    write (result)
end
```

Note the `n % (3 | 5) == 0` expression. I'm a bit fuzzy on the precise semantics, but in Icon, the concept of booleans is not like other languages. Every expression is a generator and it may pass (generating a value) or fail. When used in an `if` expression, a generator will continue to iterate until it passes or exhausts itself. In this case, `n % (3 | 5) == 0` is a generator which uses another generator `(3 | 5)` to test if `n` is divisible by 3 or 5. (To be entirely technical, this isn't even syntactic sugar.)

Likewise, in Python (which was influenced by Icon) you can use the `in` statement to test for equality on multiple elements. It's a little weaker than Icon though (as in, you could not translate the modulo comparison above directly). In your case, you would write `Thing in (A, B)`, which translates exactly to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to express that condition without trying to add any magic to the conditional operators.

In Ruby, for example:

```
$> thing = "A"
 => "A"
$> ["A","B"].include? thing
 => true
```

Comment: That is a good and fairly terse way of doing it, if a bit unintuitive.

Comment: For mainstream languages that don't have that kind of feature built-in, there are popular libraries which add that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I know you are looking for answers that have the functionality built into the language, but here are two other means that I find work better as they solve more problems and have been in use for many decades.

Have you considered using a [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor)?

Also languages like [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29) have [macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_%28computer_science%29) which is part of the language.